# Literature on category theory/set theory

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I want to write about something simple that connects category and set theory. I was told that in $\boldsymbol{\operatorname{Set}}$, the axiom of choice is equivalent to every epimorphism being split, so it's also possible to ask which categories satisfy the axiom of choice. However, I don't know any literature on this, so my point here is if anyone knows any (beginner) books on something like this that would connect those two theories.

Comment: Be more specific. "Something" can mean a lot of things - a paper, a book, a magazine article, a student essay. What level are you, and what level is your target audience?

Comment: You might be interested in these questions: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044360/the-axiom-of-choice-for-a-category) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527421/simple-failings-of-axiom-of-choice-in-top)

Comment: For example, the book "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic" has a great reframing of the famous forcing proofs of independence of the continuum hypothesis and other results from set theory. But that's a graduate-level book.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in Rosebrugh-Lawvere's book [Sets for Mathematics](http://patryshev.com/books/Sets%20for%20Mathematics.pdf), introducing set theory in a categorical fashion, aimed towards undergraduate students. Also most books on topos theory have at least some chapters on the connection to set theory, MacLane-Moerdijk's [Sheaves in Geometry and Logic](http://atondwal.org/Sheaves_in_Geometry_and_Logic__MacLane_Moerdijk.pdf) §VI and Johnstone's [Topos Theory](https://books.google.de/books?id=zO8WAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false) come to mind. These sources are a bit more advanced though.